# Jumping from a case to another case in a different switch

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I was just wondering if it was possible to jump from Case x in Switch X, to case y in Switch Y.  For example, this is not correct but clearly explains the logic of what I am trying to achieve:

```
<?php
    Switch ($X){
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
            Goto (Switch ($Y), case y); //Incorrect code, for example only
    }
    Switch ($Y){
        case 'x':
        case 'y':
            //Do something here
        case 'z':
    }
?>
```

If this is possible then please respond with the correct syntax/code I would need to achieve this.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: you're probably wanting to to use an array and a loop rather than a switch for something like this

Comment: This shouldn't be down voted.  It is purely a question to see whether this could be achieved or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [goto](http://php.net/manual/it/control-structures.goto.php) operator as the follow

```
<?php
    switch($X){
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
            goto nextSwitch;
    }

    nextSwitch:
    switch($Y) {
        case 'x':
        case 'y':
            //Do something here
        case 'z':
    }
?>
```

Comment: The OP wants to goto the case 'y' of the second switch.

Comment: As @Thanasis has said, I would like to go to a specific case within the second switch, how would this be achieved?

Comment: Sounds like you want to take spaghetti code to extreme levels

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. In that case you can't use the `goto` operator. I would simply create a function and call it from both cases.

Comment: I wouldn't call it spaghetti code, its purely for a reset type button that, when pressed, reverts to a previous case where certain information had been displayed in order to use it for a second time.